# Not getting the desired output(no. of connected objects/islands) in this program(Segmentation Fault)?

Tags: c

I have to find number of connected objects in a given 2-D binary matrix.
After giving inputs i am not getting the output

**Error i get:** Program terminated due to "Segmentation fault" (11)

**My Test Case:**

```
Enter number of rows: 
5 
Enter number of columns: 
5 
Enter the matrix: 
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 
Number of connected objects = 2
```

**My Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef int Color;
typedef struct cell
{
 char kind;
 Color color;
} Cell;
typedef struct pos
{
 int h,v;
} Pos,Size;
typedef struct world
{
 Size size;
 Cell **cells;
} World;
typedef struct node
{
 Pos pos;
 struct node *next;
} Node;
typedef struct stack
{
 Node *np;
} Stack;
void push(Stack *s,Pos pos)
{
 Node *np=malloc(sizeof(*np));
 np->pos=pos;
 np->next=s->np;
 s->np=np;
}
int isEmpty(Stack *s)
{
 return !s->np;
}
Pos pop(Stack *s)
{
 Pos ret=s->np->pos;
 Node *next=s->np->next;
 free(s->np);
 s->np=next;
 return ret;
}
World *make_world(Size size,Stack *s);
void ruin(World *w);
void paint(World *w,Pos pos,Color *color);
int main(void)
{
 int rows,cols;
 puts("Enter number of rows:");
 scanf("%d",&rows);
 puts("Enter number of columns:");
 scanf("%d",&cols);
 Stack land={ NULL };
 World *world=make_world((Size){.v=rows,.h=cols},&land);
 Color color=0;
 while(!isEmpty(&land))
 {
    paint(world,pop(&land),&color);
 }
 printf("Number of connected objects = %d",color);
 ruin(world);
}
enum { BLANK=0,LAND='1',SEA=0,NONE=-1};
World *make_world(Size size,Stack *landList)
{
 World*w=malloc(sizeof(*w));
 w->size=size;
 w->cells=malloc(size.v * sizeof(*w->cells));
 for(int r=0;r<size.v;++r)
 {
    w->cells[r]=calloc(size.h,sizeof(**w->cells));
 }
 puts("Enter the matrix:");
 for(int r=0;r<size.v;++r)
 {
    for(int c=0;c,size.h;++c)
    {
        char ch=0;
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        if((w->cells[r][c].kind=ch)==LAND)
        push(landList,(Pos){ .v=r, .h=c});
    }
 }
 return w;
}
void ruin(World *w)
{
 for(int r=0;r<w->size.v;++r)
 free(w->cells[r]);
 free(w->cells);
 free(w);
}
void fill(World *w,Pos pos,Color *color,Cell *neighbor)
{
 if(pos.h<0 || pos.v<0 || pos.h>=w->size.h || pos.v>=w->size.v)
 return;
 Cell *cell=&w->cells[pos.v][pos.h];
 if(cell->color!=BLANK)
 return;
 if(neighbor!=NULL)
 {
    if(cell->kind!=neighbor->kind)
    {
        return;
    }
    cell->color=neighbor->color;
}
else
{
    cell->color=++*color;
}
fill(w, (Pos){.v=pos.v-1,.h=pos.h-1},color,cell);
fill(w, (Pos){.v=pos.v-1,.h=pos.h},color,cell);
fill(w, (Pos){.v=pos.v-1,.h=pos.h+1},color,cell);
fill(w, (Pos){.v=pos.v,.h=pos.h-1},color,cell);
fill(w, (Pos){.v=pos.v,.h=pos.h},color,cell);
fill(w, (Pos){.v=pos.v,.h=pos.h+1},color,cell);
fill(w, (Pos){.v=pos.v,.h=pos.h-1},color,cell);
fill(w, (Pos){.v=pos.v,.h=pos.h},color,cell);
fill(w, (Pos){.v=pos.v,.h=pos.h+1},color,cell);
}
void paint(World *w,Pos pos,Color *color)
{
 fill(w,pos,color,NULL);
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to use debugger.

Comment: When i enter the matrix it doesn't stops after i enter 5*5. The loop is an infinite one i suppose

Comment: `c,size.h` typo as `c<size.h`.  It is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380073/971127) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the inner for-loop `for(int c=0;c,size.h;++c)`, which should be `for(int c=0;c < size.h;++c)`. 
Condition `(c,size.h)`, as written in your code, is a [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other), which evaluates all the operands separated by a `,`, but "returns" only the result of the last expression as rvalue. Hence,  `(c,size.h)` has the same effect as if you wrote `size.h` as condition, and if `size.h` is not `0`, the condition will always evaluate to `true`; Consequently, you run into an infinite loop, increasing `c` all the time and yielding undefined behaviour (probably a segmentation fault).

Anyway, please turn on warnings in your development environment / compiler call; I suppose that you should have gotten something like "expression result unused" on expression `c`...